# How to open file as root in GUI text editor on mac os

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, root

I need all my files in certain directory to be accessible only by root. So I do the `chown` and `chmod` commands to set privileges to 700 template where file owner is root. After that if I open files with nano everything works ok: if I run it with sudo I can see contents of files and edit it; if not root then I can see just an empty file which I can't edit or modify. Then I try to open files with Sublime2 as `subl 1.txt`. With or without sudo it just appears to show an empty file. Then I try `sudo open 1.txt` to open with the default TextEditor and then I see a message that I don't have permissions. The same if I try anything like `sudo open -a (any other text editor from my apps) 1.txt` the permissions message is shown. I've tried to google for `gksu` for mac but people say that sudo is enough. Please guys, any ideas on the topic are welcome. Thank you much!

Comment: This is a general-computing problem rather than a programming problem, so it's probably going to be closed soon. I will simply say *don't do this.* Running a GUI app as root on macOS opens a lot of really serious security holes, and there's a good reason that it's a lot more difficult to do these days than it used to be. Find a text editor that has the feature to authorize to read/write root-owned files, or just use something like vi/emacs to edit the files.

Comment: I think it's a security feature that osx no longer allows 'open' to use root privileges anymore, no matter if you 'sudo' or not. It was working in the past, but apple must've decided that it's better to not allow that at some point. The solution is to avoid using 'open' in the first place.

Comment: 4 years in, still open